# Add unknown columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How do I programatically add unknown columns in data.table?

Section 1:6 of the [FAQ](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) states:

> To create expressions use the quote() function. We refer to these as quote()-ed expressions to save
>   confusion with the double quotes used to create a character vector such as c("x"). The simplest
>   quote()-ed expression is just one column name :

But I don't seem to be doing it correctly:

```
library(data.table)

counts <- as.data.table(data.frame(
    u = 1:3, 
    v = 3:5,
    w = 0:2,
    x = 3:5,
    y = 6:8,
    z = 1:3
))

form_nms <- c("t", "u", "v", "w")
forms <- form_nms[form_nms %in% colnames(counts)]
forms_exp <- paste(forms, collapse=" + ")
forms_exp2 <- quote(forms_exp)

counts[, formal := eval(forms_exp2)]
counts[, formal := eval(forms_exp)]

## Both give...
##    u v w x y z    formal
## 1: 1 3 0 3 6 1 u + v + w
## 2: 2 4 1 4 7 2 u + v + w
## 3: 3 5 2 5 8 3 u + v + w
```

What I'd like is:

```
##    u v w x y z formal
## 1: 1 3 0 3 6 1      4
## 2: 2 4 1 4 7 2      7
## 3: 3 5 2 5 8 3     10
```

Comment: I'd do it as: `counts[, formal := Reduce(\`+\`, .SD), .SDcols=intersect(form_nms, names(counts))]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a quoted expression, but you don't always get one by calling `quote()`. There is no variable evaulation inside the `quote()`. You could do what you want here with

```
forms_exp3 <- parse(text=forms_exp)[[1]]
counts[, formal := eval(forms_exp3)]
```

Here we use `parse()` to create a language element from the text. `parse()` will return an expression (which is kind of like a list for language objects) so we just want to return the first language object. Compare

```
str(forms_exp)
# chr "u + v + w"
str(forms_exp2)
# symbol forms_exp
str(forms_exp3)
# language u + v + w
```